# Splitting Dataframe column values and assigning to other columns, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, split

I have the below data in a dataframe and would like to split from the first occurrence of ;

df:

```
IT;3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
KR;3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
MX;3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
NL;3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
NZ;3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
PH;3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
PT;3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
RU;3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
SG;3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
TR;3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
US;3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I

df['itemNew'] = df['item'].str.split(';', 1)[1]
```

Giving error: ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Expected results in new column as below:

```
3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
3P;J;1;C;A;TO1;A;A;A;I
```

Tried this:

```
df['itemNew'] = ''
df['itemNew'] = df['item'].str.split(';', 1).str[1]
```

Warning message occurs:
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Try: `df = df.assign(itemNew=df['item'].str.split(';', 1).str[1])`

Comment: Or just remove the first line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need `str` for select second lists created by `split`:

```
df['itemNew'] = df['item'].str.split(';', 1).str[1]
```

Use `copy`:

```
df= Mapping.loc[Mapping['DatasetId'].isin(['bisdss2016', 'imffsi2017apr', 'imfifss2017', 'imfifss2017aug', 'wbdb2016oct'])].copy()
```

If you modify values in `df` later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (`Mapping`), and that Pandas does warning.

Comment: super working fine,,, but i got some warning message: "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame."

Comment: i think it is in code above. Can you show your 2 rows of code above it?

Comment: If remove `df['itemNew'] = ''` warning too?

Comment: yes, actually I create df by filtering some value like df= Mapping.loc[Mapping['DatasetId'].isin(['bisdss2016', 'imffsi2017apr', 'imfifss2017', 'imfifss2017aug', 'wbdb2016oct'])]

Comment: @faithon.gvr.py Try `df = Mapping.loc[Mapping['DatasetId'].isin(['bisdss2016', 'imffsi2017apr', 'imfifss2017', 'imfifss2017aug', 'wbdb2016oct'])].copy()`

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension. In this case atleast (no `NaNs`), it's 2x faster than `str.methods`

```
In [233]: df['itemNew'] = [x.split(';', 1)[1] for x in df['item'].values]
```

Timings, that surprises me too.

```
In [229]: df.shape
Out[229]: (11000, 1)

In [230]: %timeit [x.split(';', 1)[1] for x in df['item'].values]
100 loops, best of 3: 5.42 ms per loop

In [231]: %timeit df['item'].str.split(';', 1).str[1]
100 loops, best of 3: 11.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: Yes, but it not support NaNs

Comment: If some NaN it failed. So `str.` method are slowier, because working with NaNs nice.

Comment: Good point. I'll let OPs decide based on their data, if NaNs never occur or handled earlier anyway, better to not use `str.method` here.

Comment: @John Galt, Thanks, for new way...will try this also